# Boost spirit qi semantic actions shows "No overloaded function found" error for call to a plain function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, boost-spirit, function-call

I have a grammar as follows:

```
template <typename Iterator>
    struct Grammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator>
    {
        Tokenizer obj;
        template <typename TokenDef>
        Grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
            : Grammar::base_type(path)
        {

            using boost::spirit::_val;
            path
                =
                (*(*(tok.separator[(&print)]) >> token[(&print)] >> *(tok.separator[(&print)]))
                    |
                    (token)[(&print)]
                    ) >> boost::spirit::eoi; // Look for end of input.
            token
                = (tok.identifier)[_val = boost::spirit::qi::_1]
                ;

        }
        boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator> path;
        boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, std::wstring()> token;
    };
```

Im trying to call this plain function:

```
void print(std::wstring const& t)
    {
        std::wcout << t << std::endl;
    }
```

But I get "no matching overloaded function found" error, but the same grammar worked with when I called function object, but I need to modify it to plain function for a different reason, please suggest any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Something tells me there are multiple overloads for `print`, possibly brought in by ADL. The SSCCE/MCVE will tell us.